# python class variable reset?

Tags: python, html-parser

I am having this issue now, so I have a HTMLParser using HTMLParser library class like this

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    temp = ''
    def handle_data(self, data):
        MyHTMLParser.temp += data
```

I need the temp variable because I need to save the data somewhere else so I can assess somewhere else.

My code use the class looks like this:

```
for val in enumerate(mylist):
    parser = HTMLParser()
    parser.feed(someHTMLHere)
    string = parser.temp.strip().split('\n')
```

The problem with is that this temp variable is storing whatever I stored it before, it doesn't reset even tho I am declaring a new instance of the parser every single time. 
How do I clear this variable??? I don't want it to save whatever's there from the previous loop

Comment: Use `self.temp` and move `temp` into the constructor

Comment: looks like you are making a new instance of the `HTMLParser` instead of `MyHTMLParser`

Comment: @jk622 they are the same, I pasted it wrong but they are the same in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have stated, the problem is that you are adding the data to the class variable instead of the instance variable.  This is happening because of the line `MyHTMLParser.temp += data`

If you change it to `self.temp += data` it will change the data of each instance rather than storing it up in the class.

Here is a full working script:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    temp = ""

    """Personally, I would go this route"""
    #def __init__(self):
    #   self.temp = ""
    #   super().__init__()
    """Don't forget the super() or it will break"""

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.temp += data # <---Only real line change

"""TEST VARIABLES"""
someHTMLHere = '<html><head><title>Test</title></head>\
<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>'
mylist = range(5)
""""""""""""""""""

for val in enumerate(mylist):
    parser = MyHTMLParser() #Corrected typo from HTML to MyHTML
    parser.feed(someHTMLHere)
    string = parser.temp.strip().split('\n')

    print(string) #To Test each iteration
```

Answer (score 3):

`temp` in your code is a `class attribute`, it will only initialize when first time `python interpreter` see this class, so `temp = ''` will only run for once.

So, move it to `__init__` to make it as a `object attribute` is a good solution.

But, if you insist on to let it as a `class attribute` just as you said in comments:

> Is there anyway to declare a global variable that can be used inside the class and elsewhere?

BTW, this could not be called as `global variable`, it is a `class attribute`.

Then you had to reset it by yourself. In your code, `handle_data` as a callback will be called by `feed` multiple times, so there is no chance to do it in `handle_data`, you had to do it out of class.

For your code, this could be something like follows with `lineA`, just FYI:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    temp = ''
    def handle_data(self, data):
        MyHTMLParser.temp += data

for val in enumerate(mylist):
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    MyHTMLParser.temp = '' # lineA
    parser.feed(someHTMLHere)
    string = parser.temp.strip().split('\n') # lineB
```

See `lineA`, it will reset the `temp` to empty so every instance will not affect each other even you declare it at the start of the class as you needed.

But, pay attention, you **should not** replace `lineA` with `parser.temp = ''` or assign any value to `parser.temp`. This will make a new `object attribute` with the name `temp`, then `parser.temp` in `lineB` will no longer use the `class attribute` any more which then make your aim not reach.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because every time you call `MyHTMLParser.temp` you get a new variable (`''`).

What you need to do is add `temp` to the object itself. You do this in the constructor:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp = ''

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.temp += data

    # use a getter
    def get_temp(self):
        return self.temp
```

Now, the `temp` variable *belongs* to the object itself. And if you have several `MyHTMLParser` objects, they will each have their own `temp` variable.

Comment: Is there anyway to declare a global variable that can be used inside the class and elsewhere? I was trying to declare a temp=' ' at the beginning of the file and then do a global temp inside the class, but that didn't work

Comment: You could pass a variable (`temp`) into your _object_ via the constructor that could then be shared by all and/or referenced elsewhere: ```parser = HTMLParser(temp)```